# Difference between declaration annotations and type annotations

Tags: java, annotations, jls, type-annotation

Java 8 introduced type annotations with JSR308. According to the Java language specifications

> type annotations can be used anywhere a type is used, such as
>   declarations, generic arguments, casts etc.

I'm relatively new to Java, Java 8 was the first version of java I used, so I'm not familiar with non-'type annotations', i.e. declaration annotations.

How are declaration annotations different from type annotations? I want to know because I keep hearing about them in manuals and it looks like 'type annotations' are a superset of 'declaration annotations'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both type annotations and declaration annotations still exist in Java, and they are distinct and non-overlapping.

A **type annotation** can be written on any use of a **type**.
It conceptually creates a new, more specific type.
That is, it describes what values the type represents.

As an example, the `int` type contains values ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...
The `@Positive int` type contains values 1, 2, ...
Therefore, `@Positive int` is a subtype of `int`.

A **declaration annotation** can be written on any **declaration** (a class, method, or variable).  It describes the thing being declared, but does not describe run-time values.  Here are examples of declaration annotations:

```
@Deprecated
class MyClass { ... }
```

says that programmers should not use `MyClass`.

```
@Override
void myMethod() { ... }
```

says that `myMethod` overrides a declaration in a superclass or interface.

```
@SuppressWarnings(...)
int myField = INITIALIZATION-EXPRESSION;
```

says that the compiler should not issue warnings about code in the initialization expression.

Here are examples that use both a declaration annotation and a type annotation:

```
@Override
@NonNull String myMethod() { ... }

@GuardedBy("myLock")
@Regex String myField;
```

Note that the type annotation describes the value, and the declaration annotation says something about the method or use of the field.

As a matter of style, declaration annotations are written on their own line, and type annotations are written directly before the type, on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

Most annotations right now are declaration annotations, for example `@Override`:

```
class Foo implements Runnable {
    @Override // applies to the declaration of Foo.run()
    public void run() {
    }
}
```

Type annotations expand the possible annotation targets to uses of types which are *not* declarations (casts, type arguments and so on). Type annotations can appear *in* declarations, but type annotations are not a superset of declaration annotations. For example, `@Override` is never a type annotation.

In cases which are ambiguous, for example `@Foo int x;`, [JLS §9.7.4 outlines specific rules for whether it's the declaration or type that's considered to be annotated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4). In some cases, it's even considered as both.

The following are a few unambiguous examples of type annotations:

```
// cast
String str = (@Foo String) take();
// type argument
List<@Foo String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

---

I suppose I could also add that the issue with type annotations at the moment is that there's no official API that lets an annotation processor (basically a compiler plug-in) do anything meaningful with them. As a result of this, type annotations are generally only used by third-party tools, like Lombok and the Eclipse compiler.